# How to copy/share AWN settings?

Tags: backup, settings, awn

How can I copy/backup/save Avant Window Manager (AWN) settings and apply these settings to another computer?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Just open dock-properties and choose "themes":

[image]

Then press "edit"-button (in german "Anpassen")

[image]

Then press "export theme" (in german "Thema exportieren")

[image]

After this you save the theme, copy it to your computer and "install" (see screenshot 1) it in awn again.

Comment: I was going to ask the same question. Good answer.

Comment: Thanks. I wanted to copy the full settings including theme. Like, what are the applets added in AWN and how its organized,etc. I could see those are stored in gconf. But, I couldn't export and import those.

Comment: today i tried out 11.04 beta. Liked unity style. Going forward unity will do all the jobs. Awn is my favorite docker for last 3 years. Great job.